# How may the Monitor Interval effect the Network Traffic ~.1 [GB/s] in ZeroMQ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, typescript, zeromq

So, I have a process that manages a bunch of workers that uses a **`REQ/REP`** and a **`PUB/SUB`** pattern for each worker bee. I set the monitor interval to **`250 [ms]`** and all has been working fine.

When I deploy onto a Windows server, and startup the resource monitor, the amount of network traffic (bytes written) by this node process is upwards of **`64-100 [MB/s]`** and that doesn't include any real application transactions yet, because the traffic is there whether I start the children or not, and it doesn't abate when the children do come online.

Suspecting the interval setting I played with increasing the value, and do notice that higher interval values (less often) does lead to a decrease in the traffic, but the cost of that is it takes that long to detect connect/disconnect events.

Now I haven't tried to narrow it down yet to whether it is actually the **`REQ/REP`** pattern or the **`PUB/SUB`** pattern that is the issue, but I am curious what part of the documentation I overlooked that would explain this behavior.

We are probably going to swap out the ZeroMQ in favor or GRPC next release, but I have questions to answer now.

I believe I have tagged everything relevant to the operating environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *When I deploy onto a Windows server, and startup the resource monitor, the amount of network traffic (bytes written) by this node process is upwards of 64-100 [MB/s]*

I guess you are already pretty aware of how the low-level ZeroMQ native API tools actually work down there, under the hood. If not, may read how the native API implementation under the calls to **`zmq_socekt_monitor()`** itself sets another layer of ZeroMQ pipes-and-plumbing, so as to become able to monitor its own activities ( events et al ) and review, how well do Windows ( native or virtualised platforms ) cope with using **`inproc://`**-channels setup amongst your **`Context()`**-instance(s)' pool-of-IOthread(s) and the said bunch of bees. Try to tweak the number of IO-threads and may be better map the **`ZMQ_AFFINITY`** in a different manner, so as to split the " ***background*** " workloads

> ...
> Each call to this method creates a **`ZMQ_PAIR`** socket and binds that to the specified **`inproc://`** endpoint. To collect the socket events, you must create your own **`ZMQ_PAIR`** socket, and connect that to the endpoint.
>   
>   The events argument is a bitmask of the socket events you wish to monitor, see Supported events below. To monitor all events, use the event value **`ZMQ_EVENT_ALL`**.
>   
>   Each event is sent as two frames. The first frame contains an event number (16 bits), and an event value (32 bits) that provides additional data according to the event number. The second frame contains a string that specifies the affected **`TCP`** or **`IPC`** endpoint.

This is my suspect `#1` for the root-cause of seeing `~ 100[MB/s]` of traffic @ `250 [ms]` cadence, as reported above <sub>( having no MCVE, as you have explained above ).</sub>

Turning on all possible events ( in the herd ) may generate indeed some volume of traffic, as each FSA-event reports a colourfull state since launched, irrespective of the intended `PUB/SUB + REQ/REP` Scalable Formal Communication Archetype patterns' state, covering all the intended ZeroMQ infrastructure's connectivity lifecycle, propagating each such configured monitored-event during either of  `{ setup | operations | termination | release}`-phase:

```
{ ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECTED,
  ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECT_DELAYED,
  ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECT_RETRIED,
  ZMQ_EVENT_LISTENING,
  ZMQ_EVENT_BIND_FAILED,
  ZMQ_EVENT_ACCEPTED,
  ZMQ_EVENT_ACCEPT_FAILED,
  ZMQ_EVENT_CLOSED,
  ZMQ_EVENT_CLOSE_FAILED,
  ZMQ_EVENT_DISCONNECTED,
  ZMQ_EVENT_MONITOR_STOPPED
  }
```

so data flow even before the first intended ZeroMQ infrastructure's `.connect()` has appeared.

---

**Epilogue:**

In case there are also the said **`[GB/s]`** flows reported on the  L3+ network layers, the SIGINT experts may better request due dilligence and clarifications from the platform vendor(s), what has been behind such a platform's self-reporting ( if not even a back-door class ) practices, that may explain, sure - better stop, such remarkable network exgress data-flows.  <sub>*Did someone dare to say the platform might have been hacked?*</sub> Well, hope it was not.

Comment: Just want to follow up. Thank you for a very detailed explanation. I had submitted a longer monitor interval, and that helped, but then one day, while out riding my bike, the thought hit me. "Why monitor at all?" So, I treat my resources as always connected, and of course, the network traffic dropped to nearly 0, and my components operate the same as they always have. It seems like a win.

Comment: The more a reason to ride a bike more often **:o)**